# How to find out the active security provider on Windows programmatically?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Windows 10 has UI for showing the active security provider (in the Windows Security application, click on "Virus & threat protection" and then on "Manage providers"). How do I find out programmatically which security provider is currently active?

(More specifically, I need to find out whether Windows Defender is the active security provider, or whether a different antivirus application is active).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't ideal, but you can use WMI to get some information. Note this does not work on Windows Server, and requires Vista or later. You can get clearer information from `SecurityCenter` namespace on Workstation OS before Vista.

```
void Main() {
    var av_searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\SecurityCenter2", "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
    foreach (ManagementObject info in av_searcher.Get()) {
        Console.WriteLine(info.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString());

        var ps = ConvertToProviderStatus((uint)info.Properties["ProductState"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(ps.SecurityProvider.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ps.AVStatus.HasFlag(AVStatusFlags.Enabled) ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
        Console.Write("Signatures are ");
        Console.WriteLine(ps.SignatureStatus.HasFlag(SignatureStatusFlags.UpToDate) ? "up to date" : "out of date");
        Console.WriteLine()l
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum ProviderFlags : byte {
    FIREWALL = 1,
    AUTOUPDATE_SETTINGS = 2,
    ANTIVIRUS = 4,
    ANTISPYWARE = 8,
    INTERNET_SETTINGS = 16,
    USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL = 32,
    SERVICE = 64,
    NONE = 0,
}

[Flags]
public enum AVStatusFlags : byte {
    Unknown = 1,
    Enabled = 16
}

[Flags]
public enum SignatureStatusFlags : byte {
    UpToDate = 0,
    OutOfDate = 16
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ProviderStatus {
    public SignatureStatusFlags SignatureStatus;
    public AVStatusFlags AVStatus;
    public ProviderFlags SecurityProvider;
    public byte unused;
}

public static unsafe ProviderStatus ConvertToProviderStatus(uint val) => *(ProviderStatus*)&val;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does give me the information I need.